# Django-REST-Framework: Validating GET request parameters?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint for `/GET/` request which takes some required parameters like `/resources/?bag_id=11`

`bag_id` represent the Bag object in application.
In my scenario this is how i want to handle this call:

1) if no bag_id is provided as a part of url, then raise error saying `'bag_id' is a required parameter`.

2) if bag_id is provided , then check if a Bag object exists for this , if not then raise error saying `'no bag found'`.

I was wondering which might be the correct place to handle this:

Should i override list() and handle those cases there or somewhere else? Which is the correct place to check these two conditions ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the first question: you are describing an URL, which will be served from your backend. If the URL doesn't exist, then the response should be 404, right ? Or if you are looking to build a browsing urls structure, then the GET on the url without ID should yield back the list of items.
Where to check for the condition: nowhere - the framework does this for you.

For the second question: you could validate the form of the id by using RegEx in the url definition. If the resource doesn't exist on the server, there are several debates out there on what is the proper answer: 404 or 200 with description in headers or content. My recommendation: you are asking for a non-existing resource on the server - you should answer with 404.
Where to check for the condition: nowhere - the framework does this for you.

Comment: Please provide code references